# Trim all spaces in start all tables cells in document (Mircrosoft Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I need clean all spaces in start of cells of all tables in document.

I tried to use and edit the mentioned VBA Macro in the below link but I could not make it work

this one

```
Sub TrimCellSpaces()
Dim myRE As New RegExp
Dim itable As Table
Dim C As Cell
myRE.Pattern = "\s+(?!.*\w)"
For Each itable In ThisDocument.Tables
    For Each C In itable.Range.Cells
        With myRE
            C.Range.Text = .Replace(C.Range.Text, "")
        End With
    Next
Next
```

End Sub

[Remove trailing whitespace at the end of table cells](https://superuser.com/questions/1028319/remove-trailing-whitespace-at-the-end-of-table-cells?newreg=858e7cd351574eec94b7b60e7f79138e)

Would you please help me

[I want to remove the red marked spaces at least start of cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvT1i.png)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression pattern `\s+(?!.*\w)` finds trailing spaces.
You need to modify it. As you want to remove spaces at the beginning of cells, the regex pattern must be `^\s+`.
You also need to set Global and Multiline properties to True.
So the code will be:

```
Sub TrimCellSpaces()
    Dim myRE As New RegExp
    Dim itable As Table
    Dim C As Cell
    
    With myRE
       .Pattern = "^\s+"
       .Global = True
       .Multiline = True
       For Each itable In ThisDocument.Tables
           For Each C In itable.Range.Cells
            C.Range.Text = .Replace(C.Range.Text, "")       
           Next
       Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I tried this Pattern before but it added paragraph marks in all cells, I dont know why?

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud The pattern doesn't add the paragraph mark. It is added automatically when using .Replace(C.Range.Text,""). This question and its answer explain the reason why it is added.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but is there a way to remove the spaces with adding paragraph marks?

Comment: You can also do this with Word's find and replace if you use 2-stage wildcard - one to highlight all the spaces between words (which will exclude the spaces at very start before first word) - the wildcard find is >*< and the replace with nothing but set formatting to highlight (assumes you have used a highlight colour otherwise it'll highlight with 'no color'), and then a second one to find non-highlighted spaces and replace with nothing.  After that, just remove all the highlighting you've added.  You could code those steps in VBA as an alternative to regex, to avoid para mark issue.